# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION - Fetching a Random Item from an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I am trying to fetch a random item from an array containing 3 strings as follows :

```
func selectRandomImage () {
        var imageName : String? //Optional

        var arrayCount : NSNumber = animalsArray.count //Bridges to an NSNumber

        var x : Int  = Int(arc4random())%(arrayCount.integerValue)

        var name : String  = animalsArray[x] as String

        println("Name is \(name)")

    }
```

However every 5 runs or so of the code, I am getting a crash with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

Could anyone advise on what could be wrong or how to troubleshoot ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

arc4random doesent work well with swift, it crushes when you try to cast it to Int

Try `Int(rand())` instead of `arc4random()`

Comment: This always gives 1 as a result.

Comment: Int(Int(rand()))%(arrayCount.integerValue)

Comment: Makes no difference - still returns 1